# How do I use nested attributes in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been trying to implement nested attributes in my rails application for some days now. I have searched and searched but all examples seems not to be working for me. I will like someone to help me with what I want to implement.

I have a User model that is powered by Devise gem. I also have a Location and Bio model.

This is the scenario... After a User registers, he can set his current location and Bio (This is done after Registration). I want the User to be able to Update those information at the same time using one form.

What I have tried... I created a non resource controller called UserPreference and created an Update and Create action that Updates the information supplied by the User in a Field_for form for each of the models. I have also used accepts_nested_attributes in the parent model which is the User model. Both of the other models are all a One to One relationships. Please, I have been on this for days now and checked through various resources here and online.

p.s: I might not have explained this very well but I will be pleased if someone can write out the solution step by step for me as I am still a noob in Rails. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your  different models and the relations  between them ?

Comment: A User model, Location model and a Bio model. User has_one Location and has_one Bio

Comment: why Location and Bio aren't columns in the User table ?

Comment: I made them in separate table to reduce redundancy. Location has City, address, state and country colums

Comment: can you post your logs ?

Comment: It basically says params is empty: user